# how to configure Exim4 on Debian 7 so that email *from* foo.com VPS to anyone@foo.com goes to anyone@foo.com at bar.com?

Tags: email, configuration, email-server, exim, debian-wheezy

So. There's two servers---foo.com which is a VPS, and bar.com which is a shared host running cPanel and has been configured to accept mail for foo.com.

foo.com has a fresh install of Debian 7 and Exim4 running. The MX record for foo.com points to bar.com in the DNS.

I don't want to accept mail locally at foo.com VPS and so want to continue using the addresses for foo.com set up at bar.com, which seems to work fine insofar as I can send messages to anyone@foo.com from somewhere like baz@qux.com and the messages turn up fine on the bar.com server for anyone@foo.com. Likewise, I can send mail *from* the foo.com VPS to somewhere like baz@qux.com and the messages are received, no problem. Further, I can use SMTP through bar.com using Thunderbird to send messages to anyone@foo.com and they turn up fine on the bar.com server. So looks like MX record works as far as I can tell.

The problem is though, sending mail *from* foo.com VPS to a foo.com address --- the mail never gets delivered. Not locally, and not to bar.com where it should go. It just kind of disappears into some void---no errors in /var/log/mail* etc, no emails bouncing back, but the messages never arrive at bar.com host.

Currently `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/mailname` files on foo.com VPS have the entry "mailclient.foo.com" in them to avoid sending the mail locally.

And the localhost entry in `/etc/hosts` on foo.com is similarly set to *mailclient.foo.com*:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost mailclient.foo.com
```

The config for Exim4 is pretty much a default 'Internet site' config, except that the system mail name is set to mailclient.foo.com to avoid sending emails locally.

`hostname` command returns: *mailclient.foo.com* 
and `hostname -f` command returns: *localhost*

---

I'm new to mail in general, let alone Exim4 config, so there's bound to be something (or indeed a few things!) that I've done wrong...

Any ideas/leads/something to try/read?

Any and all help greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up manualroute on the `foo.com` host:

```
begin routers
fwd2bar:
    driver = manualroute
    domains = foo.com : qux.com : +local_domains
    route_data = mail.bar.com
    transport = smtp
    no_more
. . . . .
```

You have to place it at the very beginning of routers, before any other router.
Each message that has destination domain listed in the `domains` will be sended to the host `mail.bar.com`. You have to ensure that all that domains are defined as local or properly relayed on the `mail.bar.com`